# Geany 1.24: Color Chooser differences (same installer, different Windows versions)

Tags: windows, color-picker, geany

Installing Geany 1.24 from the win installer ( geany-1.24_setup.exe ) on two different 64-bit versions of Windows (desktop: Win 7 Ultimate; VPS: Windows Server 2008R2), I see different 'Color Choosers'. Both were installed entirely 'vanilla', apart from adding my own snippets file and a couple of custom syntax highlighters - again, the same across both platforms.

The Server version is exactly the same as I see in geany on Ubuntu, and includes an 'eyedropper' - which is a terrific feature that I use **all the time** (so much so that I have installed an app in Win7 to replicate the functionality).

So anyway... is there someone out there who knows about a setting that I can finagle on the desktop to get the *more better* version of the Color Chooser?

#### Win 7 Ultimate

[image: I know, right? Pretty hinky]

#### Windows Server

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Use Windows Native Dialogs' under "Edit->Preferences->General->Miscellaneous" was checked in the Win7 install. Absolutely no idea why - that's not the default. Unchecking it enables the 'good' color chooser, without a restart.